# Prove that $-1$ is a perfect square

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need help to prove the last part ( the part in bold ) of the following lemma.

Here is it:
If $q=p^t$, where $p$ is an odd prime, then exactly half the non-zero elements of $\mathbb{F}_q$ are squares. **Moreover, $-1$ is a square if and only if $q\;\equiv\;1\;(mod\;4).$**

Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 3):

It's well-known that $F_q^{*}$ is cyclic. The question asks whether this group has an element of order $4$ or, equivalently, whether $4|(q-1)$.

Edit. Here is an argument that doesn't use the fact that $F_q^{*}$ is cyclic.

If $q - 1$ is not divisible by $4$, then $F_q^{*}$ cannot have an element of order $4$.

If $q-1$ is divisible by $4$, then the Abelian group $F_q^{*}$ has a subgroup of order $4$, which is isomorphic to one of $Z/4Z$ or $(Z/2Z) \times (Z/2Z)$. The latter possibility is absurd, however, since $X^2 - 1$ would have $4$ roots. (This repeats a portion of the proof that $F_q^{*}$ is cyclic.)

Comment: The group being cyclic is true, but not needed: if $G$ is a finite abelian group, it has subgroups of order $m$ for every $m$ that divides $|G|$.

Comment: @egreg $(Z/2Z) \times (Z/2Z)$ has no elements of order $4$.

Comment: @egreg If a finite abelian group has elements of order $4$, does every element (or one specific element in our case) of order $2$ automatically have square roots?

Comment: @user49640 You forget that the group is the multiplicative group of a field. A subgroup of order $4$ cannot be the product of two cyclic groups of order $2$.

Comment: @Arthur Here the group is very special, because it has *exactly one* element of order $2$, namely $-1$.

Comment: @egreg I was not forgetting it, since it is a trivial consequence of the fact that $F_q^{*}$ is cyclic, and in fact the proof is similar. But I've included the argument in my answer now.

Comment: @user49640 Can't upvote twice. `;-)`